# Remote Image (from URL) as Media Library element

Tags: images, urls, media-library, remote

I have slow upload on my wordpress server and I want to export two very big image to external server. So I need Media Library Image to use in other component. I cant edit URL of Image. Is any plugin or solution for using remote image as Media Library?

Tnaks for help.
Marcin

Comment: This question is vague and confusing. I don't really know what you are trying to do. What does editing the image URL have to do with your slow uploads, for one?

Answer (score 0):

I have own server (mywordpress.com). At now I have two big images (as background ) on mywordpress.com page. I have asymmetric bandwidth on this server 1024/128 kBit. So Slow upload on this server causes clients waiting about 30s to load this images. My idea is to move this two big images to external server for example otherserver.com/big1.jpg  and somehow integrate media library element on mywordpress.com I want to something like this `<img src="http://otherserver.com/big1.jpg" />` instead `<img src="http://mywordpress.com/big1.jpg" />` on mywordpress.com server. That is all. Almost all elements of my page will be load from slow mywordpress.com server but two http request (GET big1.jpg) goes to fast otherserver.com this should be faster solution.

Comment: Marcin, a Q&A site don't work like a forum, please check the [faq]. This info should be added to the Question itself, you are free to [edit it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/84929/edit) whenever needed.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Editing your theme to link just the one image won't suffice? It seems like a lot of hard work to just host one or two images on another server.